# TypeScript returning arbitrary type

Tags: typescript, type-safety

I have a function that, when called, returns an object. The type of the object is unknown to the function, but supposedly known to the caller.

I don't want to use `any` or implicit any, so I have to choose: do I return `unknown` or a generic `<T>` type?

If I return `unknown` (because I don't know/care what the type is), I force the callers to cast the result, which is not convenient - especially in an `async` context, where they will need to `await` the result.

```js
async function getSomething(): Promise<unknown> {
  return JSON.parse(await unknownJsonValue());
}

const something = (await getSomething()) as Something;
// use the value - it might not be a Something, but it's clearly the caller's responsibility
```

If, on the other hand, I use generics, I kind-of promise that the returned object will be what the caller has requested:

```js
async function getSomething<T>(): Promise<T> {
  return JSON.parse(await unknownJsonValue());
}

const something = await getSomething();
// use the value - it might not be a Something even though the library "promised" that it is
```

If for some reason the result wasn't what the user expected, I broke the contract.

What are the pros and cons of each approach, other than what I already wrote?

Comment: ① Why is it inconvenient "especially" in an `async` context? `(await getSomething()) as Something;` vs `getSomething() as Promise<Something>`? ② `unknown` is the only type safe approach. The caller can choose to use a type assertion ("casting") or do some sort of testing to ensure the result is as they expect (which depends on what `Something` is, so if you want to see this you should provide a [mre] of that too). ③ But this feels opinion-y to me. I'm not sure the "pros and cons" are objectively so or just based on preference (a pro to me is a con to you, etc) How should we proceed?